# Error Page configuration in web.xml for JSF application

Tags: jsf, config, web.xml

I have tried to configure error page in web.xml using error-page element, but the error page is never shown rather the exceptions are thrown out in raw form to the user viewing the application.

What should I do about it? I have not found any clue as to why is this so. Any help is highly thankful.

Regards,
Asif

Comment: How exactly did you configure it? How exactly did you test it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add error pages for `Exception` as follows

```
 <error-page>
         <error-code>400</error-code>
         <location>/400.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>your.company.YourException</exception-type>
        <location>/errorPage.html</location>
    </error-page>
```

Recheck the `Exception` type if you want to show error page on all type of exception then use `java.lang.Exception`

Comment: Actually I was setting /ErrorPage.jsp which was giving error. But now i am using /faces/exceptionOccured.xhtml Which is not giving error. How can I access the exception object in exceptionOccured.xhtml

Comment: you can access exception from request with `javax.servlet.error.exception` key